# Weird problems drawing a circle

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

UPDATE2: Tried rendering just a quad. [image: FAIL!]

UPDATE: The FULL code is here. Somebody can please confirm any problem with my code? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8489109/HelloAndroid.7z

I've been trying to draw a circle with Opengl ES 1.0. I've used a lot of SDL and OpenGL on the Windows platform and been using mostly glBegin and glEnd because of the low polygon count that my games used.

Pasted down is my code that is called when the object is created.

```
    float ini[]=new float[360*3];
    ByteBuffer temp=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ini.length*4);
    temp.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertex=temp.asFloatBuffer();
    int i;
    float D2R=(float) (3.14159265/180);
    for (i=0;i<360;i++){
        float XX=(float)(Math.sin(i*D2R)*size);
        float YY=(float)(Math.cos(i*D2R)*size);
        ini[i*2]=XX;
        ini[i*2+1]=YY;
        ini[i*2+2]=0;
    }
    vertex.put(ini);
    Log.d("GAME","SPAWNED NEW OBJECT");
    length=ini.length;
    //vertex=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(temp.length*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    //vertex.put(temp);
    vertex.position(0);
```

Now here is the draw code

```
Log.d("OBJECT","DUH WRITE");
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glTranslatef((float)x,(float)y,0);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT,0, vertex);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, length);
gl.glPopMatrix();
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

It draws a circle (when it actually decides to run), and adds some wierd lines.
An example here: 
[image]

It's the fault of?

```
gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glViewport(0, 0, arg1, arg2);
gl.glOrthof(0,(float)arg1,(float)arg2,0,-1,1);
gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't make sense:

```
float ini[]=new float[360*3];
/* ... */
for (i=0;i<360;i++){
    float XX=(float)(Math.sin(i*D2R)*size);
    float YY=(float)(Math.cos(i*D2R)*size);
    ini[i*2]=XX;
    ini[i*2+1]=YY;
    ini[i*2+2]=0;
}
```

You allocate a multiple of 3 elements, but multiply with a stride of 2. Either do

```
float ini[]=new float[360*2];
/* ... */
for (i=0;i<360;i++){
    float XX=(float)(Math.sin(i*D2R)*size);
    float YY=(float)(Math.cos(i*D2R)*size);
    ini[i*2]=XX;
    ini[i*2+1]=YY;
}
/* ... */
gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT,0, vertex);
```

or

```
float ini[]=new float[360*3];
/* ... */
for (i=0;i<360;i++){
    float XX=(float)(Math.sin(i*D2R)*size);
    float YY=(float)(Math.cos(i*D2R)*size);
    ini[i*3]=XX;
    ini[i*3+1]=YY;
    ini[i*3+2]=0;
/*        ^         */
/*        ^         */
}
/* ... */
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT,0, vertex);
```

Also you're using glDrawArrays wrong. You don't use the length of the array in bytes, but the count of vertices to draw – 360 in your case.

```
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 360);
```

Comment: Yeah, I've found it like 10 minutes after I've started to read every line. It's my first time using glDrawArrays, glVertexPointer, so thanks so much for your help! It's now working!